# Database retrieval in Android causing error

Tags: android, database

In my application I have to retrieve data from a database. My requirement is I have to retrieve data by satisfying the condition that I have to sum the total column where group column should be household.

I have written this query:

```
public String addhousehold()
{
    long sum = 0;

    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE groups=Income", null);

     if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
     {
         sum = cursor1.getLong(0);
     }

     cursor1.close();

     String housetotal=String.valueOf((long)sum);       
     System.out.println("house="+housetotal);

     return housetotal; 
}
```

But I get an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.budget1/com.budget1.Report}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Income: , while compiling: SELECT SUM(total) FROM incomexpense WHERE groups=Income.
>   As I am new to this please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: did u checked your database tables, i think it don't have column called Income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be:

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
         "SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE groups='Income'",null);
```

if (Income) is a string.. and if not, then you should make sure the column exists..